# Массив в массиве

Tags: c++

У меня есть двумерный массив. Мне необходимо при выполнении какого-нибудь условия присвоить значение случайному элементу массива. Массив большой, и если написать `arr[rand()][rand()]`, то программа долго угадывает. С каждым шагом, количество элементов, которые отвечают условию, уменьшается (и в конце, когда остается один элемент, который опять-таки отвечает условию, программа  ну  прям очень долго его угадывает).

Чтобы реализовать данную проблему я  создала новый массив, элементами которого являются элементы ранее созданного массива.

```
arr1[size] = {arr2[0][0], arr2[0][1], arr2[1][0], arr2[1][1]};
```

Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы при присвоении значения элементу `arr1[0]`, это же значение было присвоено и массиву `arr2[0][0]`,  `arr1[0]` — `arr2[0][1]`.
Надо, чтобы рандомно изменялись все элементы, кроме тех, что находятся на диагоналях.
А у меня получается:

> arr1[0] = 5
>
> arr2[0][0] = точно не 5

Как быть? Или есть другой вариант? Динамические массивы еще не проходили.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    srand(time(0));
    const int SIZE = 5;
    char array1[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };

    // Заполняем массив первоначальными значениями
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            if (i == j || i == SIZE - j - 1) // Если диагональ
            {
                array1[i][j] = '0';
            }
            else
                array1[i][j] = ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Максимальное количество элементов, что соответствуют размеру 5
    char array2[SIZE*3+1] = { 0 }; 
    int k = 0;
    cout << "Array1\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            cout << array1[i][j];
            if (i == j || i == SIZE - j - 1)
            {
                array2[k] = array1[i][j];
                ++k;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Array2\n";
    int rand_num = rand() % k;
    array2[rand_num] = 'X';
    for (int i = 0; i < k ; i++) {
        cout << array2[i] << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Change array1\n\n";

    // Тут ничего не меняется, а мне нужно
    // чтобы элементу массива array[i][j] присвоилось значение Х
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            cout << array1[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант положить туда указатель на одну и ту же переменную целую... Ну или ссылку.

Comment: @pavel еще не проходили. из пройденного: условный оператор, циклы, многомерные массивы. генератор случайных чисел.

Comment: @AnastasiiaMelnyk а как вы определите диагональ  в массиве 4x4?  3x3 - понимаю, или вам нужно чтобы менялись только `0` элементы?

Comment: код редактировала, мне нужно чтобы рандомно менялись все элементы, кроме тех, что находятся на диагонали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял наложенные "ходом обучения" ограничения (нельзя указатели, нельзя функции) то решение может выглядеть так:

- пусть двухмерный массив (матрица) - размером NxN
- сформировать массив индексов `ind` всех элементов в матрице, кроме диагональных. В этом массиве будет `L=N*(N-1)` элементов. Для матрицы 3х3: `1 -> m[0][1], 2 -> m[0][2], 3 -> m[1][0], 5 -> m[1][2], 6 -> m[2][0], 7 -> m[2][1]`. **Обратите внимание**: здесь пропущены индексы 0, 4, 8, соответствующие элементам на диагонали.
- для замены случайного элемента:

  1. взять `i=rand(); pos=ind[i]` элемент из массива индексов
  2. убрать i-й индекс из массива, сдвинув все индексы справа от него на 1 влево и уменьшив `L` на 1
  3. заменить в матрице элемент `m[pos/N][pos%N]`

В коде это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
int ind[N*(N-1)];
int L = N*(N-1);
// заполняем индексы
for (int ind_p=0, arr_p=0; arr_p<N*N; arr_p++)
{
    if ( i % (SIZE+1) > 0 )
        ind[ind_p++] = arr_p;   
}

// пока не обработаем все индексы
while ( L != 0 )
{
    int i = rand() % L;
    int pos = ind[i]; // индекс в матрице

    // удалим индекс из массива
    --L;
    for ( ; i < L; ++i)
        ind[i] = ind[i+1];

    if ( uslovie ) // "какое-нибудь условие"
        matrix[pos/N][pos%N] = 'X'; //замена случайного элемента
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - вы копируете значения элементов одного массива в другой, после чего это - разные вещи, никак не связанные между собой.

В рамках вашего подхода вам надо просто хранить указатели на элементы вашего первого массива:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    srand(time(0));
    const int SIZE = 5;
    char array1[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };
    //заполняем массив первоначальными значениями
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            if (i == j || i == SIZE - j - 1) //если диагональ
            {
                array1[i][j] = '0';
            }
            else
                array1[i][j] = ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    char * array2[SIZE*3+1] = { 0 }; // максимальное количество элементов, что соответствуют размеру 5
    int k = 0;
    cout << "Array1\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            cout << array1[i][j];
            if (i == j || i == SIZE - j - 1)
            {
                array2[k] = &array1[i][j];
                ++k;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Array2\n";
    int rand_num = rand() % k;
    *array2[rand_num] = 'X';
    for (int i = 0; i < k ; i++){
        cout << *array2[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Change array1\n\n";
    //тут ничего не меняется, а мне нужно чтобы в элемент массива array[i][j] отобразилось значение Х
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            cout << array1[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```